# Define a primitive apply with purely scheme procedures

Tags: scheme, sicp

In SICP's chapter [3.1.1 Mutation is just assignment](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%25_sec_Temp_363),

the `cons` is represented purely in terms of procedures:

```
(define (cons x y)
  (define (dispatch m)
    (cond ((eq? m 'car) x)
          ((eq? m 'cdr) y)
          (else (error "Undefined
                 operation: CONS" m))))
  dispatch)
```

and in [chapter 4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html), a primitive `eval` is defined purely as well as `cons`

```
(define (eval exp env)
  (cond ((self-evaluating? exp) exp)
        ((variable? exp) (lookup-variable-value exp env))
        ((quoted? exp) (text-of-quotation exp))
        ((assignment? exp) (eval-assignment exp env))
        ((definition? exp) (eval-definition exp env))
        ((if? exp) (eval-if exp env))
        ((lambda? exp)
         (make-procedure (lambda-parameters exp)
                         (lambda-body exp)
                         env))
        ((begin? exp) 
         (eval-sequence (begin-actions exp) env))
        ((cond? exp) (eval (cond->if exp) env))
        ((application? exp)
         (apply (eval (operator exp) env)
                (list-of-values (operands exp) env)))
        (else
         (error "Unknown expression type -- EVAL" exp))))
```

However, the book did not try to define a primitive-apply, instead wrap the builtin apply as

> We have assumed instead that we have saved a reference to the underlying apply by doing
>   `(define apply-in-underlying-scheme apply)`

In the `4.1 Metalinguistic abstraction`, the illustration take `apply` as granted as well as the builtin `cons`, `car` and `cdr`.

How could define a primitive `apply` ?

Comment: `apply` for user-defined procedures is defined in Chapter 4. `apply` for primitive functions is a conditional that checks the name of the (primitive) function, and then selects the appropriate operations for each function: it perform `cons`, `cdr`, etc. So to write it one should know the primitive functions and know how to manage the evaluation of each of them.

Comment: The only reason for using the builtin apply is so the interpreted language can reuse other builtin procedures as primitives. If you don't allow such primitives, but only procedures defined within the interpreter, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to define a `primitive-apply`.  This comes from the language that you use to implement the evaluator.

In case you work with a meta-circular evaluator the `primitive-apply` comes inside the scheme system that you use (for example, mit-scheme, guile, etc provides you an `apply`).  In case that you implement a language in some other language apart from scheme, like C, the `primitive-apply` comes written in C.

For example, if you add 2 numbers in the target language, to use the `+` operator from C to compute the result, the `primitive-apply` needs first of all to convert the representation of numbers of target language in C-like representation and after that to apply the primitive `+` (from C) and to convert the result back to target language.  This result will be returned in the target language by the `primitive-apply`.

The idea is that the implementation of the language made in C will know the representation of objects in target language and will be able to convert that representation to a similar representation that will be recognized by the C code (try to see how big numbers are implemented in some implementation and what happens internally when you add 2 big numbers with an implementation that uses [gmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) lib). See for example how [gmp](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-04/msg00547.html) is implemented in emacs lisp, what happens when you evaluate `(+ a b)` in emacs/gnu...

You need to define only the `apply` function in the target language, that you implement.

On the other hand I do not understand why you combined the question with the issue with different implementations of the constructor for lists.

Comment: Because I do not see a base case of `apply` proc to arguments, as for eval, many base cases as `number? return expr; string? return expr, etc" and all the base cases do not encapsulate another eval within them.

Comment: @Calculus I think you should write your own code using the ideas from SICP because when you try it yourself you will discover alone the answer to such questions.  There are lots of small hidden issues that you cannot see only reading SICP.

Comment: ty, I got it, that's kinds of dispatches.

Comment: @Calculus the primitive-apply is the very place where is made the connection between the low level system and the high language that you are implementing.